# How to create multi-column text layout with Pythin using `tkinter`?

Tags: python, tkinter, multiple-columns

[tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) allows us to create GUI applications in Python.  My question is to create a responsive window that:

- A column has a fixed width, but a flexible height.
- When window's width increases, more columns are added.
- When window's width decreases, columns are removed.
- When window's height increases, columns become longer.
- When window's height decreases, columns become shorter.

Each column has texts that moves to other columns depending on their sizes.  For example:

- If columns' heights increase, then more text is shown inside them.  The 1st column will be taking more texts from the 2nd column, and the 2nd column will be taking texts from the 3rd (or the buffer).

My question is:  how to achieve this effect with tkinter?

Comment: There is no built-in widget which does that, you will have to code your own custom class.

Comment: @j_4321 - What if I model each paragraph as a frame.  Is there any way to let the frames get populated and move around in the right order by using `.pack()`?  Or something smart?

Comment: In this design, do you plan for the user to be able to directly edit the text in the columns? Will these columns have anything other than text (embedded widgets or images)? Will the text all use the same font?

Comment: @BryanOakley - the user won't do anything.  User will read it just like a classical multicolumn newspaper.  The number of columns will adjust based on window's width to fill most columns.  The user in the configuration will only specify column width (the app will fill maximum columns based on window size).  Then, to answer your question, within each column will be title, maybe 1 photo, and some text; no formatting by the user.  If the user adjusts the window size, the number of columns must adjust accordingly, and so is their content (e.g. some items in a column will move to other columns).

Comment: @caveman Tkinter's layouts do not work the way you want so you cannot put widgets in a given number of columns such that they go in the next column if the previous one is filled.  Given your above comment, I think your best option is to use text widgets (in disabled mode) and grid them on a single row. Then, the key problem is to write a function that distribute the content in the different columns given the current geometry of the window.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in widget implementing this kind of column feature. Tkinter does not have a "column" layout manager that behaves this way either. It is therefore necessary to create a custom widget.

My solution is to create the columns with `Text` widgets in a container `Frame`.

- You set the desired column width (in character) and then update the number of columns when the window is resized with a binding to `<Configure>` (see the first part of `.resize()` method in the example below). The `Text` widgets are displayed with `.grid(row=0, column=<column number>, sticky="ns")` on a single row and adapt to the row height thanks to the option `sticky="ns"`.
- To split the content between the different columns, I use the [peer feature](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M89) of the `Text` widget. The leftmost column is the main `Text` widget and I create peer widgets that have the same content for the other columns (see the first part of `.resize()` method in the example below). This way all the columns have the same content but the part of it which is displayed can be changed independently. To do so, I use `.yview_moveto(<column number>/<total number of columns>)` to display the proper part of the content in each column. However, for this to work when the content is shorter than the available display space, I need to pad the content with newlines to get a nice column display (see the second part of `.resize()` method in the example below).

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MulticolumnText(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **text_kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, class_="MulticolumnText")
        # text widget options
        self._text_kw = text_kw
        self._text_kw.setdefault("wrap", "word")
        self._text_kw.setdefault("state", tk.DISABLED)  # as far as I understood you only want to display text, not allow for user input
        self._text_kw.setdefault("width", 30)
        # create main text widget
        txt = tk.Text(self, **self._text_kw)
        txt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")  # make the Text widget adapt to the row height 
        # disable mouse scrolling
        # Improvement idea: bind instead a custom scrolling function to sync scrolling of the columns)
        txt.bind("<4>", lambda event: "break")
        txt.bind("<5>", lambda event: "break")
        txt.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: "break")
        self.columns = [txt]  # list containing the text widgets for each column
        # make row 0 expand to fill the frame vertically
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)

    def __getattr__(self, name):  # access directly the main text widget methods
        return getattr(self.columns[0], name)

    def delete(self, *args):  # like Text.delete()
        self.columns[0].configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.columns[0].delete(*args)
        self.columns[0].configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

    def insert(self, *args):  # like Text.insert()
        self.columns[0].configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.columns[0].insert(*args)
        self.columns[0].configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

    def resize(self, event):
        # 1. update the number of columns given the new width
        ncol = max(event.width // self.columns[0].winfo_width(), 1)
        i = len(self.columns)
        while i < ncol: # create extra columns to fill the window
            txt = tk.Text(self)
            txt.destroy()
            # make the new widget a peer widget of the leftmost column
            self.columns[0].peer_create(txt, **self._text_kw)
            txt.grid(row=0, column=i, sticky="ns")
            txt.bind("<4>", lambda event: "break")
            txt.bind("<5>", lambda event: "break")
            txt.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: "break")
            self.columns.append(txt)
            i += 1

        while i > ncol:
            self.columns[-1].destroy()
            del self.columns[-1]
            i -= 1

        # 2. update the view
        index = self.search(r"[^\s]", "end", backwards=True, regexp=True)
        if index:  # remove trailling newlines
            self.delete(f"{index}+1c", "end")
        frac = 1/len(self.columns)
        # pad content with newlines to be able to nicely split the text between columns
        # otherwise the view cannot be adjusted to get the desired display
        while self.columns[0].yview()[1] > frac:
            self.insert("end", "\n")
        # adjust the view to see the relevant part of the text in each column
        for i, txt in enumerate(self.columns):
            txt.yview_moveto(i*frac)


root = tk.Tk()
im = tk.PhotoImage(width=100, height=100, master=root)
im.put(" ".join(["{ " + "#ccc "*100 + "}"]*100))
txt = MulticolumnText(root, width=20, relief="flat")
txt.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
txt.update_idletasks()
txt.tag_configure("title", justify="center", font="Arial 14 bold")
txt.insert("1.0", "Title", "title")
txt.insert("end", "\n" + "\n".join(map(str, range(20))))
txt.insert("10.0", "\n")
txt.image_create("10.0", image=im)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]